# Audio interface outputs lower volume from the monitor outputs

Tags: production

I own Behringer UMC202 HD audio interface, and a pair of Yamaha HS8 monitors. When I plug a monitor into the headphone jack, it is very loud, however, once I connect it to the dedicated monitor outputs on the back, the volume substantially decreases.

Do I have a faulty interface, or is this expected. If so, could someone explain why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quite normal.  Though they use similar plugs and sockets, the Headphone and Line Outputs are electrically different.   Plug your headphones into the Headphones output, plug your speakers into the L & R Main Outs, using either the 1/4" jacks or the XLRs.

Comment: Thank you. Also, I stumbled upon this article https://geekmusician.com/line-out-vs-headphone-out/

Comment: @Pepa Zdepa  That article uses a lot of words to do very little clear explanation!

Comment: It’s also not correct, if you feed in a mic or guitar source a line out will also be an amplified out. The difference is in the purpose and how it is intending to deliver the signals it is given. A line out amplifies and audio signal to line level and aims to transfer the voltage that represents that signal to the variety of equipment that may receive it. Current is irrelevant. A headphone out is also an amp but one that is attempting to deliver the current that a pair of headphone drivers needs to do some work shifting some air. A small amount of air compared to a speaker, but a similar idea.